# VBA Excel Use With + And for specifying the object properties

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use the With statement for more than 1 element.

In the code, I have:

```
    Dim bow As Worksheet
    Set bow = Sheets("Building Overwiew")
    Dim BldOvImgDiv1 As Shape, BldOvImgDiv2 As Shape
    Set BldOvImgDiv1 = bow.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 260, 4, 260, 325)
    Set BldOvImgDiv2 = bow.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 8, 325, 535, 325)
    BldOvImgDiv1.Name = "BuildingOverviewConnector1"
    BldOvImgDiv2.Name = "BuildingOverviewConnector2"
    With BldOvImgDiv1 And BldOvImgDiv2
    .line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With
```

The code looks correct, but no progress is shown.
I have to take down the second element, then it starts to work.

Is there any option of applying With statement for more than 1 item?

Comment: No, there is not. For this purpose though, you could use a shaperange: `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(BldOvImgDiv1.Name, BldOvImgDiv2.Name)).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

That will not work. `With` is just an abbreviation so that you don't have to repeat an object name over and over again - it cannot be used for more than one object.

As you just want to set the color, it makes not much sense to use a `With`-statement, you can simply use

```
BldOvImgDiv1.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
BldOvImgDiv2.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

If you want to set more than one property and you don't want to repeat the code, consider to create a Sub for this.

```
FormatConnector BldOvImgDiv1
FormatConnector BldOvImgDiv2

(...)

Sub FormatConnector(Sh As Shape)
    With Sh
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
        .Line.BeginArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
        .Line.Weight = 3
    End With
End Sub
```